# Making An Offline Transaction At The NodeJS Console

Tags: legacy-protocol, offline, raspberry-pi

I am making an offline wallet web app to use with my [open source airgapped encrypted device - the PrivateKeyVault](https://github.com/johnshearing/PrivateKeyVault/blob/master/README.md).

The web app will be modeled after [this one](https://github.com/ixuz/iota-offline) which is seen used in [this video](https://youtu.be/hKLVcqpdBLc). The reason I don't just use the wallet app above is because I want to understand how it all works and writing it myself using sample code is a good way to gain understanding. Another reason is that although I believe the sample code was written with the kindest intentions and is not infected with malware of any kind, I have no way to know for sure and I do not have enough skills to perform an audit. So my strategy to reduce the chances of malware infestation is to write the app as simply as possible using only well trusted dependencies.

Right now, I know little about NodeJS, Expressjs, iota.js, or javascript.
To get started I am trying to:
1. Create the signed bundle trytes on the offline computer using NodeJs.
2. Pass the trytes to an online machine.
3. Broadcast the trytes to the tangle from the online machine using NodeJS.

The following NodeJS script is run on my offline device to create a signed bundle which shows up on the console output as what appears to be a very large array of trytes. The array (the signed bundle) is also listed below. Then I copy the "array like" output to the clipboard and make a secure transfer [through the airgap to an online device](https://youtu.be/3MwJOj3t8cI). Then using the online computer at the bash console a NodeJS script containing the signed bundle is executed to broadcast the said signed bundle. This NodeJS script is also listed below. On attempting to run this last script I get an error which is also listed. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and show me how to broadcast the signed bundle using a NodeJS script at the online computer? Thanks

The following file is saved as sign-bundle.js and is run from the offline raspberry pi bash command prompt with the following command.
`node sign-bundle.js`

```
//////////////////////////////////////
// Sign Bundle Using Offline Computer
//////////////////////////////////////

const { createPrepareTransfers } = require('@iota/core'); 
const { asciiToTrytes } = require('@iota/converter');


let seed = 'FATTCNIQXGTTCSKIUVPRQXNRAGSHDGTGGGTOHQPMDBXHSDCNHPYQRCNI9AXDLIVCCA9KATTHSOSZZOIDV';
let fromAddress = 'AMECMIEELJKYZPQLBVSMJLSVPQFDSDZHTIWGORVJD9OUDGYINMOABRINKLW9HFVSFAKUQSWTJGCGSILS9MGNBSOAIA';
let fromAddressIndex = 1;
let fromAddressBalance = 19500000;
let toAddress = 'J9Q9PHLNIZXIFUNMRYYKDBTGANXNQLWVYNAYMYWIBSSGZDBVWYSHGAWTGH9FCYWQAAHAYEMA9CXTGMILDMLSKVDBXD';
let securityLevel = 2;
let transferAmount = 2000000;
let remainderAddress = 'AYKJNRHMHA9CHSLREPDJBRMYLPOBJRGYPFYYNDSVBJYWEIEVCEQPRBQSEHXSFKLCBQJADSZSYJLUKBCGWKDHOCYROD';
let message = '';


// Construct a transfers object
let transfers = [{
  'address': toAddress,
  'message': asciiToTrytes(message),
  'value': transferAmount,
  'tag': 'JRSOFFLINE'
}];

// Add a remainder address if specified by the user
if (remainderAddress) {
  transfers.push({
    'address': remainderAddress,
    'message': asciiToTrytes(message),
    'value': fromAddressBalance - transferAmount,
    'tag': 'JRSOFFLINE'
  });
}

// Construct an options object that includes the input
let options = {};
if (transferAmount > 0) {
  options = {
    'inputs': [{
      'keyIndex': fromAddressIndex,
      'address': fromAddress,
      'security': securityLevel,
      'balance': fromAddressBalance
    }]
  };
}

// Sign the bundle
createPrepareTransfers()(seed, transfers, options)
  .then((bundleTrytes) => {
    console.log("Success! Transaction bundle signed!");

    console.log(JSON.stringify(bundleTrytes));

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
  });
```

The following is the array? of trytes produced by the above script.

```
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
```

And the following is the NodeJS script which is run on the online raspberry pi at the bash console which produces the error. The script is saved as Send-IOTA.js and is run with the following command.
`node Send-IOTA.js`

```
///////////////////////////////
// Broadcast Signed Bundle Using Online Computer
///////////////////////////////

const iotaLibrary = require('@iota/core');

const iota = iotaLibrary.composeAPI({
  //Lookup healthy nodes at https://iota.dance/
  //provider: 'https://nodes.devnet.thetangle.org:443'
  provider: 'https://nodes.thetangle.org:443'
})



const myTrytes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

let parsedTrytes = "";

parsedTrytes = JSON.parse(myTrytes);



// Create a wrapping function so we can use async/await
const main = async () => {

  try {
    // Send bundle to node.
    const response = await iota.sendTrytes(parsedTrytes, 3, 14);
    console.log('Completed TXs');
    response.map(tx => console.log(tx));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

main()
```

Finally, the following is the error message returned by NodeJS at the bash console of the online computer which is trying to broadcast the signed bundle.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/iota/iota-workshop/code $ node a-4.1-send-tokens-.js
undefined:1
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

SyntaxError: Unexpected token V in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/iota/iota-workshop/code/a-4.1-send-tokens-.js:19:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:236:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:560:3)
pi@raspberrypi:~/iota/iota-workshop/code $
```

Thanks for your help,
John

Comment: your `myTrytes` value is already an object (an array), but you have to use `JSON.parse` on Strings. So either you do `myTrytes = '["x", "y"]';` instead of `myTrytes = ["x", "y"];` or you omit the `JSON.parse` for parsedTrytes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy-network and it is a good idea to keep only Shimmer/ShimmerEVM and latest IOTA Chrysalis questions

Comment: I agree. Please close the question

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @mihi!
That was it.
Got rid of JSON.parse and put myTrytes directly into the sendTrytes function.
The working code is as follows.

The script is saved as Send-IOTA.js and is run with the following command.
`node Send-IOTA.js`

```
///////////////////////////////
// Broadcast Signed Bundle Using Online Computer
///////////////////////////////

const iotaLibrary = require('@iota/core');

const iota = iotaLibrary.composeAPI({
  //Lookup healthy nodes at https://iota.dance/
  //provider: 'https://nodes.devnet.thetangle.org:443'
  provider: 'https://nodes.thetangle.org:443'
})

const myTrytes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

// Create a wrapping function so we can use async/await
const main = async () => {

  try {
    // Send bundle to node.
    const response = await iota.sendTrytes(myTrytes, 3, 14);
    console.log('Completed TXs');
    response.map(tx => console.log(tx));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

main()
```

Now I can send IOTA securely.
The next step is to wrap these scripts in a very simple web app.